# How to use mapvalues() function to transform integer variables into factor variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

How to use mapvalues() function to perform the below operation (converting integer variable into factor variable)?

```
library(MASS)
data(birthwt)
birthwt<-birthwt %>% mutate(low=as.factor(low),race=as.factor(race),smoke=as.factor(smoke),ptl=as.factor(ptl),ht=as.factor(ht),ui=as.factor(ui),ftv=as.factor(ftv))
```

Comment: `birthwt %>%  mutate_if(is.integer, as.factor) ` ? Why do you want to use `mapvalues` ?

Comment: my teacher asked me to do it like that :-)

Comment: I doubt if you can change class of variables using `mapvalues`. AFAIK it used to replace values.